# Multicast sender identification

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, multicast

I need to be able to determine what is the IP of a specific sender of a multicast message from the receiver standpoint, but not the multicast IP which they share. In other words, how do you broadcast your presence for unicast connections through multicast.

Working on python and also looking for advanced socket documentation and examples.

Comment: If the excercise is not to write it yourself, you may want to simply take a look at [pybonjour](https://github.com/depl0y/pybonjour-python3).

Comment: It must be self built, as I will use it for a desktop application, and the connection management is part of the implimentation.

Comment: AFAIK, a multicast packet only has its destination set to the multicast IP. i.e., `socket.recvfrom` should still give you the sender's IP.